# net-snmp is unknown for agentx extention of quagga daemons MIBs

Tags: net-snmp, quagga

I have installed net-snmp and built it with agentx support. For sub agent I am using quagga daemons. All the setup is on localhost. I have also did configuration changes in

- snmpd.conf
- zebra.conf
- ripd.conf
- ospfd.conf
- rc.conf

After starting `snmpd` and `quagga` in logs I see that agent X sub agent connected.

ripd.log:

```
snmp[info]: Net-SNMP version 5.7.2 agentX subagent connected.
```

but when in try to get rip MIB values I am getting the error like this:

```
Error in packet
reason (noSuchName) : there is no such variable name in MIB
```

Please help me if I missed any configuration.